# Drop extraneous decimal places when using Python's decimal.Decimal

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

When using Python's decimal.Decimal class we now have a need to drop extraneous decimal places. So for instance '0.00' becomes '0' and '0.50' becomes '0.5'. Is there a cleaner way of doing this than converting to a string and manually dropping trailing zeros and full stops?

To clarify we need to be able to dynamically round the result without knowing the number of decimal places in advance and potentially output an integer (or a string representation of one) if no decimal places are needed... is this already built-in to Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Decimal.normalize](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal#decimal.Decimal.normalize):

```
>>> Decimal('0.00').normalize()
Decimal('0')
>>> Decimal('0.50').normalize()
Decimal('0.5')
```

Comment: Thanks. Have only ever used normalize with a context in the past. Do you know what happens if the global default context is overridden?